# transitionFromViewController view not appearing

Tags: ios

I have the following code to replace one view with another in a container view with corresponding container view controller.  This is copied from the Apple documentation.

EDIT: Apple Documentation [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

```
- (void)transitionToViewController:(UIViewController*)toViewController {
    toViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:toViewController];
    // [self.view addSubview:toViewController.view];


    toViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, self.view.frame.size.width, 0);

    [self transitionFromViewController:self.childViewController
                      toViewController:toViewController
                              duration:0.5
                               options:0
                            animations:^{
                                toViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
                            }
                            completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                                NSLog(@"finished: %d", finished);
                                [self.childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                                [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

                                self.childViewController = toViewController;
                            }];

}
```

When this is executed, the toViewController.view does not actually appear.  However, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are getting called in toViewController.view.  In the completion block, the value of finished is FALSE.  So something is not working correctly.

I know that transitionFromViewController will add toViewController.view to the view hierarchy.  If I uncomment the line addSubview so that I am manually adding it, the view does appear, however the appearance methods on the view are getting called multiple times.  And in this case the finished value in the completion block is TRUE.

```
WelcomeViewController viewWillAppear
WelcomeViewController viewWillAppear
WelcomeViewController viewDidAppear
finished: 1
WelcomeViewController viewDidAppear
```

I'm pretty sure that I should not be manually adding the view to the view hierarchy based on several other examples.  Why isn't it working?

Comment: Do you have the reference to Apple's code this is in?

Comment: I meet the same question , It is not Apple very much. Do you have any better solution now? If true, please share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the code above was correct and the problem was elsewhere.  The problem was that the first time through this transition, the self.childViewController.view was not in the view hierarchy.  The self.childViewController itself was in the view controller hierarchy but the view was not.